# Coverity scan while building in Docker container

Tags: docker, static-analysis, coverity

I have a custom **Docker** container in which I perform build and test of a project. It is somehow integrated with Travis CI. Now I want to run the **Coverity scan** analysis from within the Travis CI as well, but the tricky part is (if I understand the Coverity docs correctly), that I need to run the build. The build, however, runs in the container.

Now, according to the cov-build --help

> The cov-build or cov-build-sbox command intercepts all calls to the
>   compiler invoked by the build system and captures source code from the
>   file system.

What I've tried: 
`cov-build --dir=./cov docker exec -ti container_name sh -c "<custom build commands>"`

With this approach, however, Coverity apparently does not catch the calls to the compiler (it is quite understandable considering Docker philosophy) and **emits no files**

What I *do not* want (at least while there is hope for a better solution):

- to install locally all the necessary stuff to build in the container 
  only to be able to run Coverity scan.
- to run cov-build from within the container, since:

  - I believe this would increase the docker image size significantly
  - I use Travis CI *addon* for the Coverity scan and this would
    complicate things a lot.

The Travis CI part just FWIW, tried all that locally and it doesn't work either.

I am thrilled for any suggestions to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I sort of solved the issue.

- I downloaded and modified ( just a few modification to fit my
  environment ) the [script](https://scan.coverity.com/scripts/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh) that Travis uses to download and run Coverity
  scan.
- Then I installed Coverity to the host machine (in my case Travis
  CI machine).
- I ran the docker container and mounted the directory where the
  Coverity is installed using `docker run -dit -v <coverity-dir>:<container-dir>:ro ...`. This way I avoided increasing the docker image size.
- Executed the `cov-build` command and uploaded the analysis using
  another part of the [script](https://scan.coverity.com/scripts/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh) directly from docker container.

Hope this helps someone struggling with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're amenable to adjusting your build, you can change your "compiler" to be `cov-translate <args> --run-compile <original compiler command line>`. This is effectively what `cov-build` does under the hood (minus the `run-compile` since your compiler is already running), and should result in a build capture.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the comment. I tried it using command `cov-translate --dir=./cov docker exec -ti container sh -c "<build commands>"` . But after the build I ended up with `translate_and_emit: [ERROR] No compiler settings found for docker`

Comment: `cov-translate` needs to be used as if it were the compiler itself. It looks like you're trying to use it as if it were `cov-build`. Perhaps try using `cov-build` on the command line in your comment?

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? If you mean literally add cov-build in front of the command and use the whole `cov-translate` as the build command, it does not work either. Also, the --help does not help at all.

Comment: I guess you can only translate the compiler to the one that is supported and hence listed in `cov-configure --list-compiler-types`

Comment: Okay, I somehow solved it. I'll write my approach in the answer here. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I use:

In "script", "after_script" or another phase in Travis job's lifecycle you want

1. Download coverity tool archive using wget (the complete Command to use can be found in your coverity scan account)
2. Untar the archive into a coverity_tool directory
3. Start your docker container as usual without needing to mount coverity_tool directory as a volume (in case you've created coverity_tool inside the directory from where the docker container is started)
4. Build the project using cov-build tool inside docker
5. Archive the generated cov-int directory
6. Send the result to coverity using curl command

Step 6 should be feasible inside the container but I usually do it outside.

Also don't forget the COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN to be encrypted and exported as an environment variable.

A concrete example is often more understandable than a long text; here is a commit that applies above steps to build and send results to coverity scan:

https://github.com/BoubacarDiene/NetworkService/commit/960d4633d7ec786d471fc62efb85afb5af2bed7c